# Distance Between Linestring Geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas, multilinestring

I have a shapefile dataset. Some roads (line) have the same name but are located at different places and are not connected.

Here is a picture of the roads with a same name in my geopandas datafile:

[image]

I would like to be able to measure the distance between road chunks (linestrings) to be able to rename the roads if the distance is higher than a threshold, such that each road has its own unique name.

Hence, do you know how to find the distance between linestrings ?

Comment: `line1.distance(line2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In geopandas, the geometries are shapely objects. To get a distance between any two shapely objects, you use the cleverly named `distance` method:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import geopandas

line1 = LineString([
    Point(0, 0),
    Point(0, 1),
    Point(1, 1),
    Point(1, 2),
    Point(3, 3),
    Point(5, 6),
])

line2 = LineString([
    Point(5, 3),
    Point(5, 5),
    Point(9, 5),
    Point(10, 7),
    Point(11, 8),
    Point(12, 12),
])

line3 = LineString([
    Point(9, 10),
    Point(10, 14),
    Point(11, 12),
    Point(12, 15),
])

print(line1.distance(line2))
> 0.5547001962252291
```

If you have a geopandas GeoSeries/GeoDataFrame, you need to be a little smarter about it.

```
gs = geopandas.GeoSeries([line1, line2, line3])
gs.distance(gs)
```

Returns all zeros, because it lines up `gs` to `gs` on the index, which is all the same geometries.

But:

```
gs.distance(gs.shift())
```

Gives you the distances from line1 to line2, and line2 to line3:

```
0         NaN
1    0.554700
2    0.948683
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot !! This is a great answer.