# split lines based on names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, geolocation, geopandas

I have a GeoPandas Dataframe, created from a shapefile object.
However, certian line have the same name but are at very different places.

**I want to have a unique name for each line !**
Therefore, I need to somehow split the line, if they are geometrically apart and rename them.

One could try to compute the distances between all street chunks and regroup them if they are close by.

The computation of the distance can easily be done in Geopandas: [Distance Between Linestring Geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972049/distance-between-linestring-geopandas/47972529#47972529)

A set of lines to try:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import geopandas as gpd


line1 = LineString([
    Point(0, 0),
    Point(0, 1),
    Point(1, 1),
    Point(1, 2),
    Point(3, 3),
    Point(5, 6),
])

line2 = LineString([
    Point(5, 3),
    Point(5, 5),
    Point(9, 5),
    Point(10, 7),
    Point(11, 8),
    Point(12, 12),
])

line3 = LineString([
    Point(9, 10),
    Point(10, 14),
    Point(11, 12),
    Point(12, 15),
])

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data={'name': ['A', 'A', 'A']},
    geometry=[line1, line2, line3]
)
```

Comment: dbscan clustering of sklearn over the coordinates is an option here. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html. Example usage on data: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py

Comment: Also please share all files needed. Only shp file is not enough to load the data. Details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262505/python-cant-read-shapefile/262509

Comment: Yes, all good now with loading data. Ill check clustering approach.

Comment: Ive added some basic approach with scikit-learn library. You can play with this line: "clust = DBSCAN(eps=0.5)" (change eps or even take different clustering algorithms from here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) to get needed result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use spatial clustering of each data point. The following code uses DBSCAN but maybe other types can suit better. Here are the overview of how they work: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("stackex_dataset.shp")
```

Each line of df is a number of points. We want to get out all of them to get clusters:

```
ids = []
coords = []

for row in df.itertuples():
    geom = np.asarray(row.geometry)

    coords.extend(geom)
    ids.extend([row.id] * geom.shape[0])
```

we need ids here to get the clusters back to df after the calculations.
Here is obtaining the clusters for each point (we also make data normalization to get better quality):

```
clust = DBSCAN(eps=0.5)
clusters = clust.fit_predict(StandardScaler().fit_transform(coords))
```

The next part is a little messy but we want to make sure we get only one cluster per id. We choose the most frequent cluster of points for each id.

```
points_clusters = pd.DataFrame({"id":ids, "cluster":clusters})
points_clusters["count"] = points_clusters.groupby(["id", "cluster"])["id"].transform('size')

max_inds = points_clusters.groupby(["id", "cluster"])['count'].transform(max) == points_clusters['count']
id_to_cluster = points_clusters[max_inds].drop_duplicates(subset ="id").set_index("id")["cluster"]
```

Then we get the cluster number back to our dataframe so we can enumerate our streets with the help of this number.

```
df["cluster"] = df["id"].map(id_to_cluster)
```

For this data with DBSCAN and eps=0.5 (you can play with this parameter - it is the maximum distance between points to get them in one cluster. The more the eps, the lesss clusters you get), we have this kind of picture:

```
plt.scatter(np.array(coords)[:, 0], np.array(coords)[:, 1], c=clusters, cmap="autumn")
plt.show()
```

[image]

And the number of separate streets are 8:

```
print(len(df["cluster"].drop_duplicates()))
```

If we make the lower eps, e.g. clust = DBSCAN(eps=0.15) we get more clusters (12 at this point) which separates the data better:

[image]

About messy part of code: in the source DataFrame we have 170 rows, each row is a separate LINESTRING object. Each LINESTRING consists of 2d points, number of points is different among the LINESTRINGs. So at first we get all points ("coords" list in the code) and predict the clusters for each point. There is a small possibility that we get different clusters to be presented in points of one LINESTRING. To solve this situation we get count of each cluster and then filter the maximums.

Comment: @james, df["STREET"] = df["name"] + "_" + df["cluster"].astype(str) to get street name. Ill put the explanation in the answer shortly.

Comment: @james, ive updated the post. Also eps=1.5 separate data much better.

Comment: @james please add subset="id" into drop_duplicates to this line: id_to_cluster = points_clusters[max_inds].drop_duplicates().set_index("id")["cluster"]. It can be caused when we have the same maximum number of two clusters